# Running Junit Test Cases on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, junit

I am new to Hadoop and trying to understand how to run different kind of test cases for hadoop applications.

Our application consists of pig scripts and lot of helper classes/UDF that deal with HDFS. So, from the integration test case point of view, it is good if we can test our helper classes logic on HDFS itself.

I wrote a few simple junit 4 test cases and ran the following :
hadoop  org.junit.runner.JUnitCore datamodel.TestDomesticDataModel

I got a dump of the output that we generally see for running test cases.

For running pig test cases, I can use pigunit.
So these two simple approaches may possibly solve the problem for me.

My Question:

1- Is there any catch in the simple approach for testing utility classes ? Is this guaranteed to work on all hadoop systems ? Of course checking the failure of the test scripts may be kind of manual. But other than that any issues?

2- How does "hadoop main-class-name" invocation work ?  How is the main class able to query the HDFS ?

3- I tried the same trick with jython pyunit. 
   hadoop  org.python.util.jython unitest.py  
   This seemed to work too.  In fact I integrated this with maven exec plugin and in case the test case fails, the maven build itself fails. So it is nice that errors are getting intimated.

Any thoughts on this approach for writing pyunit test cases for hadoop ?

Comment: `hadoop main-class-name` works because it has the correct hadoop configuration files available in the classpath. Instead of using `hadoop main-class-name`, we can also do
`java -classpath $(hadoop classpath):/path/to/hbase-0.98.13-hadoop2/lib/*:/opt/python-dateutil-1.5/:/opt/hadoop-2.5.2/etc/hadoop/" main-class-name`
The important things is keeping "/opt/hadoop-2.5.2/etc/hadoop/" in the classpath